# Fluent nHibernate join id and null values

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent

I think that I have now searched the Internet in all possible ways, and I didn't find the answer, or maybe just didn't understand the answer good enough to implement it into my current project. So I'm very happy with a solution here.

It's about planning, and as illustrated I have a machine, that run any hour during the week. But, in a "Nonproduction" table, I have timespans (estimatedStart - estimatedStop), where production is not possible. A nonProduction record, can be for a specific machine - but it can also be for the company. In that case the machineID will be null.

SO, what I want is to select a machine with all it's nonProduction records AND the nonProduction records where machineId is null.

[image: Diagram from MySQL]

The SQL statement would be VERY easy!

```
select * from machine m
left outer join nonproduction np on (m.machine_id = np.machineID or np.machineID is null)
where m.machine_id=119;
```

[image: The select result from the above SQL]

My fluent Machine mapping goes here: (Some code has been removed for clarity)

```
public class MachineMap : ClassMap<Machine>
    {
        public MachineMap()
        {
            Table("machine");
            Id(x => x.MachineId, "machine_id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Name, "name");
            Map(x => x.Number, "machinenumber");
            Map(x => x.Size, "size");
            Map(x => x.Data1, "data1");
            Map(x => x.Data2, "data2");
            Map(x => x.Data3, "data3");

            HasMany(x => x.NonProductions)
                .KeyColumn("machineID").KeyNullable()
                .AsBag();

        }
    }

public class NonProductionMap : ClassMap<NonProduction>
        {
            public NonProductionMap()
            {
                Table("nonproduction");
                Id(x => x.NonproductionId, "Nonproduction_id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
                Map(x => x.NonproductionTypeId, "nonproduction_typeID");
                Map(x => x.MachineId, "machineID").Nullable();
                Map(x => x.WorkerId, "workerID");
                Map(x => x.EstimatedStart, "estimated_start");
                Map(x => x.EstimatedStop, "estimated_stop");
                Map(x => x.Visible, "nonproductionvisible");
                Map(x => x.Repetitiontime, "repetitiontime");

                References(x => x.Machine)
                    .Column("machineID")
                    .Not.Insert()
                    .Not.Update();
            }
        }
```

Repository code here:

```
public IEnumerable<Machine> GetMachinesForCalendar(int[] ids = null)
    {
        Machine m = null;
        Order o = null;
        NonProduction n = null;

        var query = Session.QueryOver(() => m)
            .JoinAlias(() => m.Orders, () => o, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => m.NonProductions, () => n, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, Restrictions.Where(() => n.MachineId == m.MachineId || n.MachineId == null));

        if (ids != null && ids.Any())
        {
            query = query
                .WhereRestrictionOn(() => m.MachineId)
                .IsIn(ids);
        }

        return query
            .List()
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

    }
```

I know that the "n.MachineId == m.MachineId" in the restriction part is implied, but as I started to write, I really can't find a nice solution here.

I have to mention, that the database is very old, and contains a lot of data, so it is unfortunately not possible to re-design it. :(

Comment: Did you consider the `NotFound` mapping option when referencing `machine`? It's not cheap, performance-wise, mind.

Comment: The NonFound mapping? Worked with nHibernate for 6 years, but never heard of it.. Hmm, I will try that right away.. :)

Comment: `NotFound` is for handling "invalid" foreign keys values (ids that do not exist in the target entity table), I do not see how it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this to be doable by mappings.

I would map in the one-to-many only the machine bound nonProduction entities.

The general ones (without a machine id) would be loaded by a dedicated query, and you would merge the two lists for your processing.